# Excel Match function not finding text across row even though it's in column h

Tags: excel-formula, text-extraction

I have a wide and long spreadsheet, and I'm trying to automate finding the column that the match would be found in. I'm going to use the found column to further extract the version shown to another column.  Usually when I extract text, it's in a fixed column, but in this case column varies. The Match function is not finding the text string even though I know it's there. I'm not sure if Match doesn't work across a row to get column, or if it's the partial string I'm searching for, or something else.

```
     H                                                    I    ....   CS      CT
6   Found app.exe after Init ... ver: 111.2021.114.1...   #N/A
7                                                         Found app.exe after Init ... ver: 111.2021.114.1...
8
...
```

Where the formula in CS is:

```
=MATCH("Found app.exe after Init", H191:CQ191, 0)
```

But even though I know the 'Found application.exe after Init' is in the row, it's not finding the info, showing #N/A.  Why is that? Am I using match incorrectly? What do I need to do there?

My plan for column CT is to extract the version (my ultimate goal for this whole thing) from the column that locates this print statement like this (and I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly to extract the version):

```
=MID('CS191',SEARCH("ver:",'CS191')+15)
```

The version and text in the row will vary, other than 'Found app.exe after Init'.

Any other way to get this version would be ok.  This is using excel 365 (One Drive version).

Comment: Match is trying to find an complete match.  The whole cell would need to only contain what you are searching for, unless you use a wild card:  `=MATCH("*Found app.exe after Init*", H191:CQ191, 0)`

Comment: I'm seeing that it matches now with the wildcard, but it's not returning the column it's in.  Any ideas? It returns 1.

Comment: It is returning the relative column.  ie Column H would be 1.  So if you want the actual column either start at `A` or add `7`

Comment: I was hoping it would return the letter, not number.  I'm not sure how to convert that

Comment: why do you need to convert it?  If it is to use it in an INDIRECT, don't.  Use INDEX which accepts the column number.

Comment: I was thinking of using the above mid/search once I find the column. I'm not sure how to extract the version from the column.

Comment: How to extract the version from the string is a different question.  To return the value use INDEX(): `=INDEX(H191:CQ191,MATCH("*Found app.exe after Init*", H191:CQ191, 0))` then you would wrap that in the formula to parse the string.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks a lot! I got it working.      cs: =INDEX(A509:CQ509,MATCH("Found app.exe after Init*", A507:CQ507, 0))       ct: =MID(CS507,(SEARCH("version:",CS507))+8,15)